# Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-7

I get the folllowing error when starting my rails server using WEBrick on Windows 7:

C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integ
ration.rb:214:in `block in replace_gem': Please install the mysql2 adapter:`gem
 install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it
to Gemfile.) (LoadError)

I have made sure the database.yml had adapter as mysql2, gemfile lists mysql2. Below is my database.yml file and also gem file

```
    development:
      adapter: mysql2
      encoding: utf8
      reconnect: false
      database: elearn3_development
      pool: 5
      username: root
      password: password
      host: 127.0.0.1
      port: 3306

    test:
      adapter: mysql2
      encoding: utf8
      reconnect: false
      database: elearn3_test
      pool: 5
      username: root
      password: passsword
      host: 127.0.0.1
      port: 3306

    production:
      adapter: mysql2
      encoding: utf8
      reconnect: false
      database: elearn3_production
      pool: 5
      username: root
      password: passsword
      host: 127.0.0.1
      port: 3306
```

Gem file:
       source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
    end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

I have tried all the various options posted in other threads having the same issue, such as adding gem 'mysql2' 'version no'. It does not resolve the issue. I have the same issue while issuing sql-lite also.

Your help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: When I run bundle install, I get the following in the window. Please observe that mysql2 is not part of the using list. Is that normal?

```
    Using rake (10.0.4)
Using i18n (0.6.1)
Using multi_json (1.7.2)
Using activesupport (3.2.13)
Using builder (3.0.4)
Using activemodel (3.2.13)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using journey (1.0.4)
Using rack (1.4.5)
Using rack-cache (1.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using hike (1.2.2)
Using tilt (1.4.0)
Using sprockets (2.2.2)
Using actionpack (3.2.13)
Using mime-types (1.23)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.12)
Using mail (2.5.3)
Using actionmailer (3.2.13)
Using arel (3.0.2)
Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
Using activerecord (3.2.13)
Using activeresource (3.2.13)
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
Using execjs (1.4.0)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.3)
Using json (1.7.7)
Using rdoc (3.12.2)
Using thor (0.18.1)
Using railties (3.2.13)
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
Using jquery-rails (2.2.1)
Using bundler (1.3.5)
Using rails (3.2.13)
Using sass (3.2.8)
Using sass-rails (3.2.6)
Using uglifier (2.0.1)
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

**EDIT** After trying the instructions from http://www.mohanarun.com/how-to-install-mysql-adapter-ruby-gem-in-windows/, I see that bundle install is picking up mysql. But, I get the following erros, when I do rails server.

/* many more errors before */

pport/core_ext/load_error.rb
  369 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_su
pport/core_ext/name_error.rb
  370 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_su
pport/core_ext/uri.rb
  371 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_contr
oller.rb
  372 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_view/
railtie.rb
  373 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_con
troller/railties/routes_helpers.rb
  374 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_contr
oller/railties/paths.rb
  375 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_contr
oller/railtie.rb
  376 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_rec
ord/railtie.rb
  377 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-3.2.13/lib/action_mai
ler/version.rb
  378 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_su
pport/core_ext/class/delegating_attributes.rb
  379 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_su
pport/core_ext/module/reachable.rb
  380 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_su
pport/core_ext/class/subclasses.rb
  381 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_su
pport/core_ext/class.rb
  382 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_su
pport/core_ext/array/uniq_by.rb
  383 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-3.2.13/lib/action_mai
ler.rb
  384 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-3.2.13/lib/action_mai
ler/railtie.rb
  385 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activeresource-3.2.13/lib/active_r
esource/exceptions.rb
  386 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activeresource-3.2.13/lib/active_r
esource/version.rb
  387 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activeresource-3.2.13/lib/active_r
esource.rb
  388 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activeresource-3.2.13/lib/active_r
esource/railtie.rb
  389 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/test_uni
t/railtie.rb
  390 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/ra
iltie.rb
  391 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/all.rb
  392 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_su
pport/string_inquirer.rb
  393 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/version.r
b
  394 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/error.rb
  395 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/result.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: bugreport

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Comment: Have you run `bundle install` to install the gems listed in your Gemfile?

Comment: yes, i updated the question with the info. mysql2 is not as part of the using list. is that a problem?

Comment: Double and triple check that `gem 'mysql2'` is not commented out in your Gemfile.  If not, then run `gem list mysql` and see if the gem has been installed on your system at all.  If not, then run `gem install mysql2` and report back.

Comment: gem mysql2 is not commented out and gem list mysql shows 
mysql2 (0.2.6). I tried with installing mysql2 (0.3.11) too and did not work. I can see the active record adapter, mysql2 gem folders in my gem directory: C:\Ruby200-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems

Comment: Please try these instructions: http://www.mohanarun.com/how-to-install-mysql-adapter-ruby-gem-in-windows/

Comment: I tried these instructions. now i see that bundle install picks up mysql. But on rails server, I get the errors. I edited the question with the errors.

Comment: I tried to uninstall and redo all the installations, did not help.

Comment: i just moved to developing using ubuntu. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Make Sure to Add Following to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'mysql'
gem 'mysql2', "~> 0.3.10"
```

Then run

```
bundle install
```

Question is too old but this may help others.

Answer (score 0):

After you modified Gemfile and bundle install, you should have restart Rails server, which can reload the bundle gems

Answer (score 0):

The same problem happened in Production and the following was the problem.

1. Had to move sqlite gem to development in Gemfile
2. Had to add mysql2 gem to deployment in Gemfile
3. Had to run bundle install to update Gemlock
4. **Had to commit these changes to git and update remote git repo.**

These were steps quite specific to my production setup but i hope they would be helpful for someone else as well.